# Ruby Retrieving from Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

So i get an array of hashes like this

```
[1, {"item_name"=>"Estella Top", "item_number"=>"73", "quantity"=>"1", "option_name1_"=>"UK - 4, White"}]

[2, {"item_name"=>"Test Top", "item_number"=>"74", "quantity"=>"1", "option_name1_"=>"UK - 4, Red"}]
```

I have this create action:

```
def create
f_turn = extract_items

Page.create!(line_item_id: "#{f_turn.fetch("item_number")}",
 option_name: "#{f_turn.fetch("option_name1_")}", quantity: "#{f_turn.fetch("quantity")}")
 render nothing: true
end
```

**extract items** is a function that extracts the array.

I need those values, but for some reason, its not working.

I've also tried:

```
def create
f_turn = extract_items

f_turn.each do |key, values|

Page.create!(line_item_id: ["item_number"],
 option_name: ["option_name1_"], quantity: "["quantity"])
 render nothing: true
end
```

None of them work. With the latter, instead of the actual value, i get `"[\"item_number\"]"` as the value.
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE** Mistakes in the code

```
def extract_items
  mod_params = Hash.new{|k, v| k[v] = {} }

  ITEM_PARAM_PREFIXES.each do |item_data_key|
      key_tracker = 1
      loop do
          current_key = (item_data_key + key_tracker.to_s).to_sym
          if params.include? current_key
              mod_params[key_tracker][item_data_key] = params[current_key]
          else
              break
          end
          key_tracker += 1
      end
  end
  mod_params
end
```

Comment: Can you paste the 'extract_items' code? Were is e_values coming from?

Comment: @RichardAE 'e_values' was a mistake.

Comment: Initially your array of hashes is array of mixed content (integer and hash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your hash is in the format you posted, this should work:

```
def create
  f_turn = extract_items

  f_turn.each do |key, values|
    Page.create!(line_item_id: values["item_number"],
      option_name: values["option_name1_"], quantity: values["quantity"])
      render nothing: true
    end
  end
end
```

You weren't accessing the values from the hash by the looks of your original code.

Comment: Thanks alot! Solves my problem